# Worksheet Titles (Names) in a list, want to write a formula to be able to select the location from the worksheet selected from the list

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

For instance I have named my worksheet tabs as follows

```
SEP
OCT
NOV
DEC
```

If I want to reference the data from cell A1 in worksheet SEP I would write this formula:

```
=SEP!D10
```

I want to write a formula in order to make `SEP` a variable which can be selected from a list.

i.e. formula

```
=*worksheetname*!A1
```

my list has all the worksheet tab names, I select OCT in the list and it will return the data from

```
=OCT!A1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Indirect`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151323/en-us). In the example cell B1 is the sheet name variable.

SEP A1: `=INDIRECT(B1 & "!C1)`
SEP B1: `OCT`
OCT C1: `Hello World`

Output
SEP A1: `Hello World`

Answer (score -1):

Scenario:
You have three tabs named "Jan", "Feb", and "Mar" with the data you want in cell h4 of the respective tab.

```
A   B
```

1   Month   Result
2   Jan 80% Formula for cell B2 =INDIRECT(A2&"!h4",TRUE)
3   Feb 90%
4   Mar 85%

Comment: This is the same as the other answer, from over a year ago. Please review the existing answer(s) before you post, and proceed only if you are actually contributing something new.